# Content Moderator in Virtual assistant template

Tags: botframework

I installed the newly launched virtual assistant template (C#) of the bot framework, downloaded it from here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp and deployed it using deployment scripts and the default setup works well.

According to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-template?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#content-moderator, content moderator is optional but enabled.  It says "A middleware component is provided that screen texts and surfaces through a TextModeratorResult on the TurnState object." I see cognitive service for Content-moderator has been created and the secret key appears in the appsettings but startup does not instantate the object neither does the botservice.

But, I do not see any evidence of it in the code.  Searching keys such as "TextModeratorResult", "TurnState", "contentModerator" does not return anything.

Is this something we need to instantiate? Are there any guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* only have to add a single line to get this working. However, it looks like this hasn't been tested in awhile because there's a few steps to get this working. <strike>I'll submit a PR to fix this</strike>[PR](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/pull/2277), but for now:

1. Ensure you have `"contentModerator": "key"` set in `appsettings.json`. This should have happened automatically during deployment.
2. Remove the `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator` NuGet package from your project. It's been added to `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions` and having it in both caused a "Could Not Load Type..." error for me.
3. In `<yourProject>/Adapters/DefaultAdapter.cs` (or `DefaultWebsocketAdapter.cs` if you're using Websockets), add (near the rest of the middleware pipeline):

```cs
Use(new ContentModeratorMiddleware(settings.ContentModerator.Key, "https://<yourCMRegion>"));
```

*Note: Your endpoint region MUST be formatted like I have it, with the `https://` or it will not work. <strike>I'll roll</strike>I rolled a fix for this into [my PR](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/pull/2277)*

4. Now, you can access the moderated data in `TurnContext.TurnState.TextModeratorResult.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  After adding the one line of code, I receive this error.  Microsoft.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator.TextModeration.ScreenTextWithHttpMessagesAsync(String textContentType, Stream textContent, String language, Nullable`1 autocorrect, Nullable`1 pII, String listId, Nullable`1 classify, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: I had "/contentmoderator" in the url which was the reason for the null object error.  The solution works

Comment: @msekkappan Were you able to get this working then? If so, please "accept" it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: This worked, but found a bug.  It throws "at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.ContentModeratorMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AutoSaveStateMiddleware" and it fails before OnEventAsync